# Counting possibilities in a char. combination using a consecutive repetition criterion

Tags: php, algorithm, math, combinatorics

In PHP, given

- the final string length
- the range of characters it can use
- min consecutive repetition count possible

how can you calculate the number of matches that fits these criteria?
To draw a better picture…

```
$range = array('a','b','c');
$length = 2; // looking for 2 digit results
$minRep = 2; // with >=2 consecutive characters
// aa,bb,cc = 3 possibilities
```

another one:

```
$range = array('a','b','c');
$length = 3; // looking for 3 digit results
$minRep = 2; // with >=2 consecutive characters
// aaa,aab,aac,baa,caa
// bbb,bba,bbc,abb,cbb
// ccc,cca,ccb,acc,bcc
// 5 + 5 + 5 = 15 possibilities
// note that combos like aa,bb,cc are not included
// because their length is smaller than $length
```

last one:

```
$range = array('a','b','c');
$length = 3; // looking for 3 digit results
$minRep = 3; // with >=3 consecutive characters
// aaa,bbb,ccc = 3 possibilities
```

So basically, in the 2nd example the 3rd criterion made it catch e.g. **[aa]b** in **aab** because **a** was repeating consecutively more than once, whereas **[a]b[a]** wouldn't be a match because those **a**'s are separate.

Needless to say, none of the variables is static.

Comment: Are the characters always alphabetically consecutive? Shouldn't `$maxRep` really be named `$minRep`?

Comment: This seems more like a math question.

Comment: @nickb nope. **$maxRep** actually defines max. possible consecutive repetitions there can be. And again, another no for your first question. Characters are not static, so they can be `a,X,b` as well as `r1R`. We just know that they're unique in the provided **$range** array.

Comment: @Amine I actually agree with you, but the methods to gather the result are related to PHP so I thought I should better give it a try :)

Comment: No it doesn't. In your first example, `$maxRep = 1;`, and you describe it as "with >1 consecutive characters" and give "aa" as a possible solution. If `$maxRep` defined the "max. possible consecutive repetitions there can be", then "aa" couldn't possibly be a valid solution - It has two repetitions.

Comment: That's probably due to my lack of English skills, sorry about that. Let me edit my question.

Comment: My understanding of the question is as follows: "Given a character set C ($range), find the number of unique strings of length N ($length) where some character appears more than X ($maxRep) times in a row." - is this correct? If so, it really is completely unimportant that this is PHP - because unless you want to actually generate all the strings and validate them individually, the solution will be expressed by a mathematical formula.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen I suppose you're right. Where should I ask this, instead, you think?

Comment: @inhan: I think this is probably the best fit within the SE network, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's appropriate here... on the other hand, we do have other algorithm-type questions here, so I suppose it might still be okay - I'll let the other users figure that out. Personally, I would edit the question to make it language-agnostic - remove the references to PHP, and rewrite the examples accordingly. You might want to list all the possibilities for that first example (there are only 9, after all), and then use that as a basis for explaining your criteria.

Comment: @inhan I will ask this question at http://math.stackexchange.com/ and see where it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. All credit to **leonbloy** [@mathexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185096/number-of-words-with-a-minimal-number-of-repetitions).

```
/* The main function computes the number of words that do NOT contain
 * a character repetition of length $minRep (or more). */
function countStrings($rangeLength, $length, $minRep, &$results = array())
{
  if (!isset($results[$length]))
  {
    $b = 0;

    if ($length < $minRep)
      $b = pow($rangeLength, $length);
    else
    {
      for ($i = 1; $i < $minRep; $i++)
        $b += countStrings($rangeLength, $length - $i, $minRep, $results);
      $b *= $rangeLength - 1;
    }

    $results[$length] = $b;
  }

  return $results[$length];
}

/* This one answers directly the question. */
function printNumStringsRep($rangeLength, $length, $minRep)
{
  $n = (pow($rangeLength, $length) 
            - countStrings($rangeLength, $length, $minRep));
  echo  "Size of alphabet : $rangeLength<br/>"
        . "Size of string : $length<br/>"
        . "Minimal repetition : $minRep<br/>"
        . "<strong>Number of words : $n</strong>";
}

/* Prints :
 * 
   Size of alphabet : 3
   Size of string : 3
   Minimal repetition : 2
   Number of words : 15
 *
 */
printNumStringsRep(3, 3, 2);
```

Comment: I didn't know there's something called mathexchange. Thanks for that. I'm trying to understand this. Hold on :) Regardless, thanks for helping me find an answer.

Comment: I'm relying on this solution, hoping it's accurate. Sorry for the late action. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is best to handle this with math.

```
$range = array('a','b','c');
$length = 3; // looking for 3 digit results
$minRep = 2; // with >=2 consecutive characters

$rangeLength = count($range);
$count = (pow($rangeLength,$length-$minRep+1) * ($length-$minRep+1)) - ($rangeLength * ($length-$minRep)); // is the result
```

Now, $count is getting true result for three situation. But it may not be general formula and need to improve.

Try to explain it:

```
pow($rangeLength,$length-$minRep+1)
```

in this, we count repetitive characters like as one. For instance, in second example that you gave, we think in aab, aa is a one character. Because, two characters need to change together. We think now there is two character like xy. So there is same possibilities for both character a, b, and c namely 3 ($rangeLength) possible value for two characters($length-$minRep+1). So 3^2=9 is possible situations for second example.

We calculate 9 is for just xy not yx. For this, we multiply length of xy ($length-$minRep+1). And then we have 18.

It can be seemed that we calculated the result, but there is a repeat in our calculation. We didn't reckon with this situation: xy => aaa and yx => aaa. For this, we calculate and substract repeated results

```
- ($rangeLength * ($length-$minRep))
```

So after this, we get result.
As i said begining of the description, this formula may need to improve.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm thinking on it - whether it needs a tweak or not.

Comment: Doesn't work. For `$range = array('a', 'b'), $length = 5, $minRep = 2` it returns 58, which is greater than the size of the set defined by `$range` and `$length` (which is 32).

Comment: @Amine Yes, you are right. There is a problem with calculation of repeated results.

Comment: @Bilal your try was good but there are so many repetition scenarios to take into account I suspect only heavy combinatorics can solve this thing. I've bookmarked this as I'm very interested in knowing the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

With Math, work becomes really complex. But, there is always a way, even not beautiful as much as Math. We can create all possible strings with php and control them with regexp like below:

```
$range = array('a','b','c');
$length = 3; 
$minRep = 2; 

$rangeLength = count($range);

$createdStrings = array();
$matchedStrings = array();

function calcIndex(){
    global $range;
    global $length;
    global $rangeLength;

    static $ret;

    $addTrigger = false;

    // initial values
    if(is_null($ret)){ 
        $ret = array_fill(0, $length, 0);
        return $ret;
    }

    for($i=$length-1;$i>=0;$i--){
        if($ret[$i] == ($rangeLength-1)) {
            if($i==0) return false;
            $ret[$i] = 0;
        }
        else {
            $ret[$i]++;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $ret;
}

function createPattern()
{
    global $minRep;
    $patt = '/(.)\\1{'.($minRep-1).'}/';
    return $patt;
}

$pattern = createPattern();


while(1) 
{
    $index = calcIndex();
    if($index === false) break;

    $string = '';
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
    {
        $string .= $range[$index[$i]];
    }

    if(!in_array($string, $createdStrings)){ 
        $createdStrings[] = $string;
        if(preg_match($pattern, $string)){
            $matchedStrings[] = $string;
        }
    }
}

echo count($createdStrings).' is created:';
var_dump($createdStrings);

echo count($matchedStrings).'strings is matched:';
var_dump($matchedStrings);
```

Comment: Creating all the possibilities does not sound much feasable since you can have, say 32 digit numbers. It would take quite long (and consume incredible amount of memory) to first generate all the possibilities (which is **6.3626854411359E+45** for upper-case 27 basic latin character range for 32 digits) and then use `RegExp` for those.

Comment: A little correction to the number (I hadn't counted the alphabet explicitly): **1.9017224572685E+45**